# EasyRDF (php library): how to extract all the attributes and literals in RDF/XML?

Tags: php, xml, attributes, rdf, easyrdf

With [EasyRDF](http://www.easyrdf.org/)(PHP library), how to extract all the attributes and literals in XML/RDF?

I tried EasyRdf_Literal_XML::create(); and EasyRdf_Parser_RdfXml::parse();  EasyRdf_Literal_XML::domParse(); but I don't understand the poor documentation very well.

RDF/XML data ($input in the code below) looks like

```
<rdf:RDF>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/1964">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/1964"/>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resourc/1964_AD">
      <dbo:wikiPageRedirects rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org  
        /resource/1964"/>
    </rdf:Description>
    <dbo:abstract xml:lang="nl">Het jaar 1964 is een jaartal volgens    
      de christelijke jaartelling.</dbo:abstract>
    <rdfs:comment xml:lang="es">1964 (MCMLXIV) fue un año bisiesto 
      comenzando en miércoles</rdfs:comment>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Here is the first code to start with:

```
# Put data ($input) in the format of RDF/XML ($format) in $graph

try {
   $graph = EasyRdf_Graph::newAndLoad($input, $format);
  } 
catch (Exception $error) {
    $error->getMessage();
    return array('RDF loading problem (No RDF available or RDF data problem');
  }

$xml = EasyRdf_Literal_XML::create($graph);
$a =  EasyRdf_Parser_RdfXml::parse($xml);
```

Now, I would like to extract and count (even the nesting ones)

1) all the attributes

- rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/1964"
- rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/1964"
- rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resourc/1964_AD"
- rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/1964"

4 counts

2) all the literals

- Het jaar 1964 is een jaartal volgens de christelijke jaartelling.
- 1964 (MCMLXIV) fue un año bisiesto comenzando en miércoles

2 counts

Comment: you can use SPARQL or just use the graph API, what's wrong with the examples: http://www.easyrdf.org/examples ? I mean SPARQL is a simple query language, if you don't want to use this, you could still iterate over the RDF triple in the graph and get subject, predicate and object out of it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AKSW . To answer your questions, first, there is nothing wrong with examples. I just could not find an example I am asking for. :( In addition, SPARQL is not available. Second, I would like to use easyrdf for RDF/XML parsing in PHP, so I am just asking how to extract attributes and literals, using their syntax. In my view, working with RDF in PHP is not that great in general. Any experience, anybody?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, but attributes are not part of RDF. If you wanna count attributes in an XML file you need to parse it with proper classes. Did you mean the number of usages of "http://dbpedia.org/resource/1964" (for instance) an a triple? In that case, use `Graph` class to load XML file into Graph instance, ref: https://github.com/easyrdf/easyrdf/blob/master/lib/Graph.php#L248-L268. Offtopic: "http://dbpedia.org/resource/1964" owl:sameAs "http://dbpedia.org/resource/1964" points to itself.